# How to configure a PostgreSQL GIN index to support partial matches

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search

I'm currently using a GIN index to do lightening fast full text search queries in PostgreSQL. It works great, with the only exception being it doesn't seem to handle partial-word searches. e.g. Searching for "bob joe" can find the record containing "joe bob", but searching for "bob jo" finds nothing.

The [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/gin-implementation.html) claim "GIN can support partial match queries" but it doesn't go into any detail into how to configure it to do this. Am I misreading that? How do I enable partial searches?